# Http 400 bad request - Php file_get_contents in Persian URL

Tags: php, html, curl, file-get-contents

I'm a newbie and I have a url that contains Persian language characters.

For example this:

```
http://tabnak.ir/fa/news/577155/ویدیوی-درگیری-نیروهای-سیا-و-پنتاگون-در-سوریه-با-همدیگر-ویدیوهایی-از-جنجال-پاسخ-مشایخی-به-مجیدی-و-حرف‌های-عجیب-الویس-پریسلی-ایران
```

When I want to get the html source of that url, with this line of code:

```
$source = file_get_contents($url);
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://tabnak.ir/fa/news/577155/ویدیوی-درگیری-نیروهای-سیا-و-پنتاگون-در-سوریه-با-همدیگر-ویدیوهایی-از-جنجال-پاسخ-مشایخی-به-مجیدی-و-حرف‌های-عجیب-الویس-پریسلی-ایران): 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request in C:\wamp\www\file.php on line 25
```

I wanted to solve this problem by using the `urlencode`, but it didn't work.

The `urlencode` output of that line becomes:

```
http%3A%2F%2Ftabnak.ir%2Ffa%2Fnews%2F577155%2F%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D9%88-%D9%BE%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%A7%DA%AF%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D9%87%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%B1-%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AE-%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AE%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%AC%DB%8C%D8%AF%DB%8C-%D9%88-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%81%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%B9%D8%AC%DB%8C%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3-%D9%BE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%B3%D9%84%DB%8C-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86
```

Which is not a correct url address, and I can't get contents again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this ? This way, you should be able to do the file_get_contents on the encoded url

```
$url = 'http://tabnak.ir/fa/news/577155/ویدیوی-درگیری-نیروهای-سیا-و-پنتاگون-در-سوریه-با-همدیگر-ویدیوهایی-از-جنجال-پاسخ-مشایخی-به-مجیدی-و-حرف‌های-عجیب-الویس-پریسلی-ایران';
$url = mb_convert_encoding($url, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
$source = file_get_contents($url);
```

EDIT (TESTED THIS AND WORKS) :

Try this, maybe by encoding the part of the URL where there are arabic character, it might work :

```
$link = 'http://tabnak.ir/fa/news/577155/ویدیوی-درگیری-نیروهای-سیا-و-پنتاگون-در-سوریه-با-همدیگر-ویدیوهایی-از-جنجال-پاسخ-مشایخی-به-مجیدی-و-حرف‌های-عجیب-الویس-پریسلی-ایران';
$exploded = explode('/',$link);
$exploded[6] = urlencode($exploded[6]);
$urlimplode = implode($exploded,'/');
$source = file_get_contents($urlimplode);
echo $source;
```

Comment: **No** , it didn't work. error : `Warning: file_get_contents(http://tabnak.ir/fa/news/577155/&amp;#1608;&amp;#1740;&amp;#1583;&amp;#1740;&amp;#1608;&amp;#1740;-&amp;#1583;&amp;#1585;&amp;#1711;&amp;#1740;&amp;#1585;&amp;#1740;-&amp;#1606;&amp;#1740;&amp;#1585;&amp;#1608;&amp;#1607;&amp;#1575;&amp;#1740;-&amp;#1587;&amp;#1740;&amp;#1575;-&amp;#1608;-&amp;#1662;&amp;#1606;&amp;#1578;&amp;#1575;&amp;#1711;&amp;#16p;#1583;&amp;#1740;-&amp;#1608;-&amp;#1581;&amp;#1585;&amp;#1601;&amp;zwnj;&amp;#1607;&amp;#1575;&amp;#1740;-&amp;#1593 in C:\wamp\www\file.php on line 26`

Comment: @dodojoe I edited my answer, and tested it on my local server, and it works fine. :) You only need to urlencode the part where there are arabic characters.

Comment: Thanks honey, it really helped ♥♥♥

Answer (score 0):

In my case, where I wanted to pass a parameter with `Get`, I did as follows:

```
$message = "یک پیغام تست";
$link = "http://localhost:5000/myAPI_name?msg=".$message;
$exploded = explode('=',$link);
$exploded[1] = urlencode($exploded[1]);
$urlimplode = implode($exploded,'=');
$source = file_get_contents($urlimplode);       
$source=json_decode($source,true);
```

As the content of `$message` is Persian, I had to perform encoding just for anything after `=`